# Restoring stdout and stderr to default value

Tags: linux, shell, redirect, exec, stdout

In shell script, We can change the default input to a File using the  exec command as follow :

```
  exec 1>outputfile
```

However, if in the same script if I want to restore the stdout descriptor '1' to the default (terminal). How can we achieve that?

Comment: From [Gilles' answer on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91716/323093):
`exec &>/dev/tty`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This example

> Example 20-2. Redirecting stdout using exec
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # reassign-stdout.sh
>
> LOGFILE=logfile.txt
>
> exec 6>&1           # Link file descriptor #6 with stdout.
>                     # Saves stdout.
>
> exec > $LOGFILE     # stdout replaced with file "logfile.txt".
>
> # ----------------------------------------------------------- #
> # All output from commands in this block sent to file $LOGFILE.
>
> echo -n "Logfile: "
> date
> echo "-------------------------------------"
> echo
>
> echo "Output of \"ls -al\" command"
> echo
> ls -al
> echo; echo
> echo "Output of \"df\" command"
> echo
> df
>
> # ----------------------------------------------------------- #
>
> exec 1>&6 6>&-      # Restore stdout and close file descriptor #6.
>
> echo
> echo "== stdout now restored to default == "
> echo
> ls -al
> echo
>
> exit 0
> ```

appears to show what you want.  It came from [the ABS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17891.html#REDIR1), where there is a small amount of discussion and other relevant information.

Comment: Can you explain from where we are getting file descriptor '6' in above example?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation I pointed to the shell actually provides 10 numbered file descriptors for use in this way, with the first three assigned to stdin stdout and stderr.   It also notes that there is some good reason not to use '5', because that one is inherited by child proceses. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#FTN.AEN17823

Comment: Ok, I got it. We are storing the Default STDOUT in 6 and then restoring it back from 6. This is what I have been looking for. Besides, the link you provided in the comment is also of great help. Thank you.

Comment: The ABS is not a very good reference. This answer is correct but perhaps it could link to a more authoritative and/or reliable sourcee

Comment: The link wasn't for authoritative backup, it was acknowledging where I got the information from.   I don't think an "authoritative" or "reliable" source is required at all in fact.  It either works or it doesn't :).   The point is probably moot now in that the link appears defunt (which does at least confirm your assessment of it :) )

Answer (score -2):

Try the "tee" command:

```
exec | tee outputfile
```

Look at the tee manpage for more explainations:

> *tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files*

Comment: PLease explain your answer. Provide some reference for why you suggest this.

Comment: What you are proposing is to redirect same output to STDOUT as well as outfile file. However, this has no connection with restoring back the STDOUT to default value.